# Deploy a Node app from GitHub

Tags: node.js

I develop locally and push to GitHub and my staging environment is on an EC2 instance. I currently have to ssh in to my remote instance, `git pull`, restart Node server. Is there a way this process can be automated in any way?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I wrote a blog post just last week about this - although my server-side part uses Ruby/Sinatra rather than Node, but re-writing it in Node would be very simple.

http://baudehlo.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/github-continuous-deployment-to-ec2/